# Сумма по модулю 2 - всевозможные комбинации кода

Tags: java, массивы

Дано n комбинаций кода длиной m. Как найти сумму по модулю 2 всевозможных  комбинаций из n кодов. Результаты записать в массив

```
Например:
исходные комбинации

1. 1001001
2. 1101110
3. 0110001
4. 0101100
5. 0000111
```

нужно найти сумму по модулю 2 для всех комбинаций (исходные комбинации тоже могут входить в массив):
"+" - сумма по модулю 2

```
1 =                 1001001
2 =                 1101110
3 =                 0110001
4 =                 0101100
5 =                 0000111
1 + 2 =             0100111
1 + 3 =             1111001
....
2 + 3 =             1011111
2 + 4 =             1000010
....
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 0101001
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 =     0111000
1 + 2 + 3 =         0010110
.....
2 + 3 + 4 + 5 =     1110100
2 + 3 + 4  =        1110011
....
```

порядок суммирования не важен. Важно чтобы в выходном массиве была сумма всевозможных комбинаций . 
Целый день ломаю голову над задачей. Может кому-то уже встречалось?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно задачу понял, то.

Чтобы перебрать все возможные комбинации для битов, нужно просто использовать счетчик

К примеру, есть входной массив в 5 значение 11001

Создать цикл от 0 до 2 в 5 степени. Теперь, каждое число нужно преобразовать в двоичное представление. Теперь в каждом месте, где встречается единица, соответствующий элемент входного массива необходимо сложить.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] input = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
        Map<String, Integer> output = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2,input.length); i++) {
            String str = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
            while (str.length()<input.length) str = "0" + str;
            char[] bits = str.toCharArray();
            int s =0;
            for (int j = 0; j < bits.length; j++) {
                if (bits[j] == '1') {
                    s = summ(s, input[j]);
                }
            }
            output.put(Arrays.toString(bits), s);

        }

        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> i : output.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(i.getKey() + "  :  "+ i.getValue());
        }
    }

    private static int summ(int a, int b) {
        int result = a + b;
        if (result == 2) return 0;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Я имел ввиду коечто другое: Входных массивов у нас несколько ( например 2Д массив, где каждая строка - код ). Выходной массив должен выглядеть примерно так как тот в вопросе

Comment: Ну замечательно. Что значит несколько и почему 2д? Примерно или не примерно это как? Двойку поставят если не сделаешь?